When ever I run anchor init, I get this error, I have discarded serveral projects with the hope of not getting it anymore
error: failed to parse lock file at: /home/mfoniso/Desktop/code/SOL/mycalculatordapp/Cargo.lock
Caused by:
lock file version 4 was found, but this version of Cargo does not understand this lock file, perhaps Cargo needs to be updated?

what version are you using for your project and what are the  versions of your toolchain?

I think you got it correct, it's caused by an ancient version of cargo
According to this reply to an issue on GitHub

either mean your toolchain is accidentally so ancient you didn't mean that or the Cargo team was too hasty and needs to fix its release schedules

Follow up to the above comment

The inconvenient workaround will be to avoid the new format (by not updating Cargo.lock with newer cargo versions) until the project is ready to update MSRV.

